# Create user in gitlab without e-mail?

Tags: authentication, gitlab

I'm testing out omnibus gitlab on a local VM. After disabling anonymous signup, I tried adding a new user via the `/admin/users/new` page.

It requires I associate an e-mail with the new user account, and it further doesn't permit me to specify a password, saying instead that:

> Reset link will be generated and sent to the user.
>
> User will be forced to set the password on first sign in.

Now, that's nice in the abstract, but I don't want to have to configure, harden, and maintain a separate mail server simply so that gitlab can send these e-mails. There will be few enough users of this machine that I can manually administer them (i.e. if they forget their password, they can just e-mail me directly).

Is there any way for me to simply create accounts and assign passwords without getting e-mail involved?

Worth noting in passing that while I did discover [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md), and it is nice, I'd still prefer not to have to get gmail or mailgun involved, easy though they are to setup.

Comment: This question is duplicated and answered [on StackOverflow}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704546/gitlab-signup-users-without-email-conformation)

Comment: @Synchro - Not exactly; the linked question is about setting up without email confirmation. This question is about setting up without an email address. I have a valid email configuration, but I want to create a CI service account without dedicating an entire mail address that will never be used, because my company is charged per email account. The admin screen does not allow creating a new user without an email address.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way for me to simply create accounts and assign passwords without getting e-mail involved?

GitLab supports [LDAP](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/index.html), and via [OmniAuth](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/omniauth.html), also supports OAuth-based authentications.

If you do self-managed GitLab, probably setup an OpenLDAP and a decent UI (phpLDAPadmin?) to manage your users, then connect GitLab to said OpenLDAP server. Also, do not forget to disable [GitLab's SMTP](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md#disable-all-outgoing-email).

Comment: I've got a test setup on VirtualBox with LDAP and without SMTP, but for non-root users it still asks for e-mail, and doesn't allow the user to do anything before e-mail is confirmed. A workaround for testing purposes is to impersonate the user from root account.

Answer (score -1):

Navigating to admin aria>users>new user and create it. Go to edit this user settings and setup password. Then login like this user and you will be asked to change password. Now login with new pass.